# Display nested array within flat list

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to display data from a JSON file in a FlatList, more specifically data from a nested array called "cal". here is a look at the data.

```
[
{ "cal": [
 {"doctor": 7, 
 "date_end": "2020-03-30 08:18"},......
         ],
 "medical": [
   {"name": "Dr xavier vilan", "speciality": "Cardiologue", "work": "edited", "id": 7}
            ]
}
]
```

i used fetch api to get the json file and my code looks like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
this.state={
    data: []
           }
}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('....')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((res) => {
  this.setState({
    data:res,
  })
  })
  .done();
  }

render(){
return(
<FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem={({ item) => <Text>"i want to display date_end" </Text><Text>"i want to display name" </Text>

}

          />
)
}
```

what should i wright inside my .

Comment: Is your shown data complete or are there additional values missing?

Comment: @Tim there is 2 array "cal" and "medical", some attributes missing in' cal' that i don't need